# Clicking a dynamic drop-down menu using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click a dropdown menu with a dynamic ID on Meta Business Suite (formerly Creator Studio) using Selenium.

Inspecting the element shows that class="xx xx xx" and "2o" are dynamically generated.

```
<div class="l5k26z4s snfsxcfg jbfqbifr oysqpf8i n54jr4lg kiex77na lgsfgr3h mcogi7i5 ih1xi9zn a53abz89" id="js_2o">Random Name</div>
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="js_2o"]
```

So far I have tried:

```
drp_menu = wait_5.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'js_')]")))

drp_menu = wait_5.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'js_')]")))

drp_menu = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(@id,'js_')]")

drp_menu = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(@id,'js_')]")
```

In combination with:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", drp_menu)
```

The code works if I specify Full Xpath, however, other posts suggests that this is indeed bad practice and prone to errors.

**Edit:**
Upon further testing, I noticed that the code worked, but that the clicking action was being intercepted by another element whose name also began with 'js_'. I added another condition `[contains(text(),'Facebook_Name_Page')]` and it worked.

```
drp_menu= wait_5.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'js_')][contains(text(),'Facebook_Name_Page')]")))
drp_menu.click()
```

Comment: you need show the html, then other can give more suggestion.for xpath, you can use the attrbiute of this element, also can use other element for example sibling or parent element attributes

Comment: It turns out that the code was working, but the click action was being intercepted by another element. I have edited my post including the solution. I can't share the HTML because you need to be able to access Facebook Creator Studio.